# How to escape reserved words in Python and Postgres SQL at the same time?

Tags: python, postgresql

Here is the code I have:

```
for x in range(len(un)):
   query = 'CREATE TABLE "'+un[x]+'" AS SELECT * FROM public.sample WHERE ticker = +un[x]+'
   cursor.execute(query)
```

The error I am getting:

```
LINE 1: ...E "AA" AS SELECT * FROM public.sample WHERE ticker = +un[x]+
```

The query I want to run in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE "AA" AS SELECT * FROM public.sample WHERE ticker = 'AA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just miss a quote in the query string. Try this:

```py
for x in range(len(un)):
       query = 'CREATE TABLE "'+un[x]+'" AS SELECT * FROM public.sample WHERE ticker = \''+un[x]+'\''
       cursor.execute(query)
```

Also consider using parameters, as this query is prone to SQL injection (meaning you could leak or loose your database):

```py
for x in range(len(un)):
       query = 'CREATE TABLE %(ticker)s AS SELECT * FROM public.sample WHERE ticker = %(ticker)s'
       cursor.execute(query, {"ticker": un[x]})
```